# Is there a wa to call a method immedietely after object instantiation?

Tags: c#

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(){ }

    //One of many properties 
    //set up in the same way
    private String _name;
    public String Name 
    { 
        get { return _name; }
        set {
            _name = value;
            //code that is important to run
            //only after the objects initial creation   
        }
    }

    private int _id;
    public int ID 
    { 
        get { return _id; }
        set {
            _id = value;
            //code that is important to run
            //only after the objects initial creation   
        }
    }

    public void Win()
    {
        //clean up method that wouldn't be needed
        //if I used optional parameters because
        //i would be able to set _name (and all the
        //other private properties directly without
        //using the public Set
    }
}
```

How do I call a method automatically after this kind of object creation in c#

```cs
Foo ko = new Foo() {
    ID = 4,
    Name = "Chair"
};
ko.Win(); // <-- Want this to be called automatically inside the class
```

Comment: why can't you just call `Win()` inside of the c'tor?

Comment: How does the presence or absence of optional parameters fit into your question?

Comment: I think you want [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and move `ko.Win` call into final creation of the object.

Comment: Sorry my class is not clear. There are operations performed in the properties Set method I will update.

Comment: @Mark the constructor is called before the property assignments, is why I cant place the method inside the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method that automatically called after some random set of properties is set (Which is what initialization is translated to...)

```
var foo = new Foo { Name = "bar" };
```

Is actually shortcut to:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Name = "bar";
```

When written in second form one would not expect any magical method to be called after `foo.Name` assignment.

You options:

- if you have some information that need to be set on property change - just make it a property and write code in `set` part of it.
- if you must have particular set of properties configured before object is considered "created" constructor arguments is one reasonable way to enforce it.
- you can also implement [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) that allow you to delay final construction (or use some other factory method that forces setting parameters before final object creation.

Sample of code with builder pattern:

```
 var foo = new FooBuilder { Name = "bar" }
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are always setting ID and the Name how about this?

```
private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set {
            _Name = value;
            this.Win();
        }
    }
```

Win function will always called after you set a value on the name or you can do this for ID that's your choice!

Answer (score 0):

add the Win() to the constructor. Call/put inside the constructor.

```
public Foo(string value, string value2) {
Value = value;
Value2 = valu2e;

Win();
}
```

This is the constructor. Set it manually.

Comment: That changes the semantics. `Win` will be called before assignment of the properties.

Comment: +0: Setting properties happens *after* call to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most scalable solution but why not try this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

public Foo()
{
}

public Foo( int id )
{
// Win()
ID = id;
// Win()
}

Public Foo( string name )
{
// Win()
Name = name;
// Win()
}

public Foo( int id, string name )
{
// Win()
ID = id;
Name = name;
// Win()
}

    public void Win()
    {
        //Do Stuff that would go into the constructor
        //if I wanted to use optional parameters
        //but I don't
    }
}
```

You can call `Win` before or after setting the properties.